# Unable to access (any) jar file

Tags: jar, apktool

I am trying to use apktool to rename the manifest package of an apk. I've done this in the past and I don't know what changed but now I can't seem to run any .jar files. Any time I try I get an unable to access jar file error.

This is the command I am doing:
`javaw -jar C:\Users\Nosson\New folder apktool.jar d moon.apk`.
I've tried other .jar files with the same error. The file is not blocked (though I can't seem to change the batch file from being read only, it keeps switching back). I tried reinstalling Java. Anyone have anything else I can try?

Comment: Please update your question and include the full path where `apktool.jar` is located. Please also include the error message you get when you execute the command `javaw -jar ...`. Last but not least it would be good to know which is the current directory path you are in when executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

Apktool is a command-line only program without UI.

`javaw` is for starting UI based Java programs that don't make use of command-line/terminal input/output. Therefore javaw does show a command-line window.

What happens if you start a command-line only program using `javaw`? You won't see anything.

So please always use apktool with `java` instead of `javaw`:

```
java -jar "C:\Users\Nosson\New folder\apktool.jar" d moon.apk
```

Comment: That was what I tried first, just `java` and then I tried `javaw` both gave me the same error, one gave it to me in a command line (`java`) and the other gave me the error in a separate gui (`javaw`). But the results were the same.

Comment: @Nate if you get an error message you should copy that into your question.